# Jquery Autocomplete issue with vars

Tags: jquery

I have 2 textfields with autocomplete. This fields are loaded with a response from database and works OK. In the first field, when select, several fields are filled with the json response.
Now, I need to use one of the values to filter the next autocomplete query, but i cannot do it. Sorry for my english, i hope you can understand me.

this is the first autocomplete. Works fine an fills every field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
  $("#nombre_aut").autocomplete({
     source: "cliente_data.php",
     minLength: 3,
     select: function( event, ui) {
        $( "#id_clt" ).val( ui.item.id_clt );
        $( "#nombre_clt" ).val( ui.item.nombre_clt );
        $( "#apellido_clt" ).val( ui.item.apellido_clt );
        $( "#telefono_clt" ).val( ui.item.telefono_clt );
        $( "#celular_clt" ).val( ui.item.celular_clt );
        $( "#direccion_clt" ).val( ui.item.direccion_clt );
        $( "#email_clt" ).val( ui.item.email_clt );


        }
  });
});
  </script>
```

This is the second, I need to send the ID var (id_clt) from the previous autocomplete:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

  $("#dispo_aut").autocomplete({ 
             source: "dispo_data.php?cliente=",

  });
});
  </script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i can not understand what you exactly mean. but i think if you create some variable out of first function e.g `var ClienId;` and then in `select: function( event, ui) { ClientId = ui.item.id_clt; ..... your existing code`
After success execution of first function call second one with `source: "dispo_data.php?cliente="+ClientID+"`

Comment: I do that but i get Uncaught ReferenceError: ClientId is not defined

Comment: I think that you have not declared `var ClientId;` at the start. like this `<script type="text/javascript">
var ClientId;
    $(function(){
  $("#nombre_aut").autocomplete({`

Comment: Works only in the first function. When I call it from the second is not defined. If i use var ClientID = "some"; in the second func works. But i need a real var

Comment: this means you are calling second function before first is done successfully.
you should call second function in first function's `response`.

`$("#nombre_aut").autocomplete({
  response: function( event, ui ) {
and run your second function here.
}
});`

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hrr4awa5/3/)

i think this example will make it clear.

Comment: you should add ClientId = "This is your Client ID"; in select function not in response.